# Three20 Is TTTableTextItem internet aware?

Tags: iphone, three20

The Three20 package has the following to access the net:

[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"TITLE" URL:@"http://www.example.com"]

My question concerns whether this is knows whether the internet is available? My understanding is that if the internet is not available it should say so - but the screen just stays blank.

If this is not aware, do you have any links to tutorials to add this?

I don't want to submit to Apple and get rejected in two weeks time, so I would be grateful for some advice.

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup `TTNavigator` to map `*` to `TTWebController` if you want it to open the webpage.

Check out the [TTCatalog sample code](http://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/TTCatalog/).